# Java: Is NetworkInterface.getName() a unique identifier that will not change over time?

Tags: java, xml, network-programming

I'm storing some network data in an xml file using `XMLEncode`, since it is really convenient. Unfortunately, some classes like `NetworkInterface`can't be serialized (is that the right word?) to xml by a `XMLEncoder`. Thus, I thought about simply writing a string that identifies the network interface and get the `NetworkInterface` instance by using `NetworkInterface.getByName()` method.

My question: is this name ensured to be unique and not to be changed over time (assuming that no changes are made in the network configuration of the machine)? I.e., is this name on one machine always going to identify the same network interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the NetworkInterface is unique on the same machine (your assumption: no changes in the network configuration), but the name is not at all globally unique. If you need something like this, have a look at [MAC addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

However, the name of the NetworkInterface identifies a virtual Interface (on Linux systems for example eth0 for Ethernet, ath0 for Wireless) and at the moment I don't understand why you would store the interface name, since the IP address assigned to this Interface, could change easily.

Comment: I know about MAC addresses and that the assigned IP may change; that's why I thought about storing the interface name, since it's very easy to obtain the IP of the interface from it's name. But I guess I'll use the MAC address to make sure it works out correctly.

Comment: @mort Either if you use the MAC address or the interface name, keep in mind if the machine changes from Wireless to Ethernet or the other way around, there might be no IP assigned to your stored interface. Better is to get all interfaces and then select the one best suited to you (i.e. not the local loop and with an assigned IP).

Comment: The reason for me to store the network interface is the following: The machines the software is run on usually have more then one network interface, which may cause problems with RMI. Thus, I'd like to always use the same network interface for RMI. It's unlikely that the physical network configuration will change.